# Kubernetes Garbage Collection fails - FreeDiskSpaceFailed & ImageGCFailed

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Apparently the GC of my Kubernetes cluster is failing to delete any image and the server is getting to full-disk.

Can you please guide me on where to find the logs for the ImageGC with the error trying to delete the images or to a reason of why this is happening?

```
3m         5d          1591      ip-xxx.internal     Node                                          Warning   FreeDiskSpaceFailed       {kubelet ip-xxx.internal}     failed to garbage collect required amount of images. Wanted to free 6312950988, but freed 0
3m         5d          1591      ip-xxx.internal     Node                                          Warning   ImageGCFailed             {kubelet ip-xxx.internal}     failed to garbage collect required amount of images. Wanted to free 6312950988, but freed 0
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There may not be much in the way of logs (see [this issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/15564)) but there may be Kubernetes event data. Look for events of type `ImageGCFailed`.

Alternatively you could check the cadvisor Prometheus metrics to see if it exposes any information about container garbage collecton.

Docs on the GC feature in general: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/kubelet-garbage-collection/

Comment: From the `GKE` perspective you could check the Stackdriver if there are any logs related to this issue. Also there is another (newer one) [github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/71869)

Answer (score 1):

most likely your host file system is full, can you check /var file system usage.
you can use docker-gc to cleanup old image.

https://github.com/spotify/docker-gc

Run it like this

```
docker run --rm --privileged -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /etc:/etc:ro spotify/docker-gc
```

Comment: These links are 404ing in 2019

Comment: Kubernetes has [built-in image and container garbage collection](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/kubelet-garbage-collection/), this shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @bosgood if `ImageGCFailed` is occurring, then the built-in garbage collection is failing. Not sure how to fix this - same issue here.